# Reversing a word with a Stack

Tags: java

I am new here and in programming as well. I am trying to study other topics alone since my instructor isn't enough help when I have a question so here it goes. I want reverse a word with a generic Stack.

*My pop,push,isEmpty and peek methods work (I tested them with a simpler program I made before I tried it on this one.) and the output seems to be giving me the reversed word  char by char but always giving me a null before each char!*

My questions are:
Why is this happening? And even though I have an expandCapacity method to work when the capacity is at 9 but it doesn't apply when the input passes the limit.

---

## Here's my code

```
package Stack;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseDriver<T> {
    private static String out;
    private static String in;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your sentence: ");
        in = input.nextLine();
        int size = in.length();

        ArrayStack<Character> revStack = new ArrayStack<>(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {

            char u = in.charAt(i);
            revStack.Push(u);
            if (in.length() > 9) {

                revStack.expandCapacity();

            }
        }

        while (!revStack.IsEmpty()) {
            char u = revStack.Pop();
            out = out + u;
            System.out.flush();
            System.out.print(out);

        }

    }
}
```

## Here's the Output

```
run:
Enter a word: 
word
nullr
nullro
nullrow
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Stack.ReverseDriver.main(ReverseDriver.java:37)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

## EDIT: here's the methods that I said that were working.

```
@Override
public void Push ( T element)
   {
     if (count == stack.length){
         expandCapacity();
     }
      stack[++count] = element;


       //System.out.println(count);
   }



  @Override
   public String toString()
   {
      String result = "<top of stack>\n";

      for (int index=count-1; index >= 0; index--){
         result += stack[index] + "\n";
      }
      return result + "<bottom of stack>";
   }





         @Override
    public boolean IsEmpty()
    { //Checks if array is empty
        if(count == 0){
        System.out.println("Nothing");
        }

         return count == 0;


    }


 public  T Pop() 
      {

             T output; 

         output =  (stack[count - 1]);
         count--;


         return(output);

      }



 @Override
    public T Peek()
      {
          //looks at the object at the top of this stack without removing it
     //from the stack.

          if(stack.length == 0){
         // {
      System.out.println("Cant peek a ghost");

          }

         return(stack[--count]);

      }
         // else
         // {
     // System.out.println( stack[count-1]);

         // }

     // }

      @Override
    public int Size()
    {
        //Sets the size of this vector
        if(stack.length == 0){
            System.out.println("Nothing inside");
        }

       System.out.println("The array's size is : " + count);
        return count;


    }



}
```

Comment: While I appreciate that you said it's working, can you please give us the code in the expandCapacity and isEmpty method, just to give us some more insight into why this is happening :)

Comment: Are you sure this is the same code generating the output - "Enter a word" vs "Enter a sentence"

Comment: notes: `expandCapacity` gets called 10 times if `in.length ()` is 10, is this intentional? Also, `in` and `out` should more properly be local variables in main, not statics (at least if this was a "real" program).

Comment: Yeah Philip that was my bad I edit the String and copied the old Enter a sentence and hyde totally right better to have them locals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure why you need the `ExpandCapacity` bit there, this works aswell:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {       

    String word ="reverse please";      
    Stack<Character> chStack = new Stack<Character>();      
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i ++)
    {       
        chStack.push(word.charAt(i));       
    }

    String out = "";
    while (chStack.size() != 0)
    {
        out += chStack.pop();
        System.out.println(out);

    }               
}
```

Comment: I think the stack implementation was based on an array of elements. the expandCapacity was there to increase the size of the array when needed.

Comment: Hi Chris that does work completly and you are right of expandCapacity but what if in Stack class had a parameter for input in the main class
for example: Stack<Character> chStack = new Stack<Character>(word); 
How would it be possible for it to be read like that String? When I tried using input it only output till when there was a space. 
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are asking? Do you want to read the word to reverse from the console? user366722's answer should work for that.

Answer (score 6):

```
private static String out;
```

The value in `out` is null.

```
out = out + u;
// This is null = null + u;
```

Hence the null at the beginning of your output.

You simply need to create a new String object to give `out` an initial value:

```
 private static String out = "";
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot that out works like a count variable you use to store a sum of values but in this case are strings but it needs an assignment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few notes:

- You are not writing a generic class so drop .
- Leave the iteration to for as much as possible.
- Try using Java standard classes as much as possible, in this case Stack instead of ArrayStack.
- You don't need to resize the stack, it will handle its size dynamically as you put more data in.
- You should write the string once you are done creating it not once in every step.
- Appending strings using + is very inefficient. Use StringBuilder.
- Use methods they make your code readable.

Heres the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.Stack;

public class ReverseDriver {
  public static String reverse(String string) {
    Stack<Character> revStack = new Stack<Character>();
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
      revStack.push(c);
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    while(!revStack.isEmpty()){
      builder.append(revStack.pop());
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your sentence: ");
    String in = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(reverse(in));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I dint know there was a String builder that should be more useful! I do have methods but they are in different classes sorry if I dint describe that.